# Call file from another method

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, async-await, storagefile

Newbie question here. I have this file picker:

```
public async void PickImage()
{
    FileOpenPicker ImagePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    ...
    StorageFile file = await ImagePicker.PickSingleFileAsync(); // 
    ...
}
```

And I want to use the file set by this image picker in another method. Something like this:

```
private async void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...                         the one from PickImage()
                                    v
    StorageFile copyImage = await file.CopyAsync(DateTimeFolder, "image", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    ...
}
```

It is obviously not working like this. How can I do it?

---

Ok, based on the answers I got, this is what I came up with:

```
public async Task<StorageFile> PickImage()
{
    FileOpenPicker ImagePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    ImagePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    ImagePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
    ImagePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
    ImagePicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    ImagePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
    StorageFile file = await ImagePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file != null)
    {
        IRandomAccessStream imageStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        var bmpImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bmpImage.DecodePixelHeight = 150;
        bmpImage.DecodePixelWidth = 310;
        bmpImage.SetSource(imageStream);
        ImagePreview.Source = bmpImage;
    }
    return file;
}

////

private async void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    string DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmssddMMyyyy");
    StorageFolder docs = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
    StorageFolder myDir = await docs.CreateFolderAsync("My Dir", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    StorageFolder DateTimeFolder = await myDir.CreateFolderAsync(DateTimeNow);
    //StorageFile image = await PickImage();
    StorageFile copyImage = await PickImage().CopyAsync(DateTimeFolder, "image", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    ...
}
```

But the last line gives me an error:

> 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' does not contain a definition for 'CopyAsync' and no extension method 'CopyAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `PickImage` is `void`, and it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either set a field in the class or return the `StorageFile`. I would suggest changing `PickImage()` to return the `StorageFile` so you're code would instead look like this;

```
public async StorageFile PickImage()
{
    FileOpenPicker ImagePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    ...
    return await ImagePicker.PickSingleFileAsync(); // 
    ...
}


private async void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFile pickedFile = await PickImage();
    StorageFile copyImage = await file.CopyAsync(DateTimeFolder, "image", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    ...
}
```

Or something to that effect. I'm slightly confused by the second line in your `CreateButton_Click` method because I thought you wanted to operate on the file from `PickImage` but instead you're creating a new file. If you want the `StorageFile` to persist just make it a field on the form class and set it in `PickImage`

Comment: I think you need to return `Task<StorageFile>` in the first method.

Comment: @chuex yeah, I don't know. I'm hoping the explanation is sufficient. The code is too vague for me to give a solution that just works.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Sorry for the delay, I've been busy with some personal matters and this is just a side project that I had to put down for a while. I still can't get it to work, though.
I'm going to edit my question with more complete code.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by Andre in the comments, your PickImage should return the file, so you could do the following:

```
public async StorageFile PickImage()
{
    FileOpenPicker ImagePicker = new FileOpenPicker();
    ...
    StorageFile file = await ImagePicker.PickSingleFileAsync(); // 
    ...
    return file;
}

private async void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    StorageFile copyImage = await this.PickImage().CopyAsync(DateTimeFolder, "image", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Or as answered by evanmcdonnal =P

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the location of the two methods, there are two solutions:

- If the methods are located in the same class file, you can declare `StorageFile file` as a local variable in the class file. In that way, you can reach it from the `CreateButton_click` function
- If cross threading is involved (methods are working in separate threads), you need to use delegates and invoke them. Detailed information is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx) through an example.