# How to access StorageFile from another method

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro

So im making a windows store app that you select a file with one button, via file picker, then with another button it processes that file but im having trouble getting the selected file to processing method.
Since the Picker sets one of my text blocks to the path of the file to be displayed for the user i've tried using:
`StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fullFilePath.Text);`
But due to Windows RT limitations I just get access it denied from most locations
Any other suggestions on what to try?

First button click:

```
private async Task getFile()
        {
            FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
            openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
            openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;
            openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

            StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
            if (file != null)
            {
                fullFilePath.Text = file.Path;
            }
            else
            {
                updateStatus("File Selection cancelled.");
            }
        }
```

Second button start this but needs to use the file from above

```
private async Task processFile()
{
    ...
    string content = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
    ...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call file from another method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797452/call-file-from-another-method)

Comment: @chue ah, thanks for that ill have a read through

Comment: Side note: As a general rule, you should avoid programming with file paths in Universal Windows apps - the main (only?) use for them is to pass to Win32 functions that take file paths, or possibly to display to the user. You should never save a file path anywhere and expect it to work again (*even a path to your own data*).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Yeah I figured that out but I don't know how to pass the StorageFile file through to the other method without calling it in sequence, the main reason for showing the path is so the user can see it

Comment: The easiest way is to just make the StorageFile a field in the class rather than a local variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `StorageFile` a field in your class:

```
class MyClass
{
  StorageFile m_pickedFile;

  async Task GetFile()
  {
    // Setup the picker...
    m_pickedFile = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    // Show the path to the user...
  }

  async Task ProcessFile()
  {
    if (m_pickedFile != null)
    {
      // now use m_pickedFile...
    }
  }
}
```